# paypal API credit card direct payment to paypal account

Tags: java, paypal

I'm using Paypal SDK to handle payment using paypal accounts or credit cards, I'm using Paypal REST APIs to make payment from credit card to the paypal application account, then using Paypal adaptive SDK to transfer the money from the application account to each seller's paypal account, the solution is working but the problem is paypal take 2.9% +0.3 fees for each transaction, Is there any way to use direct credit card payment to the paypal account without the need to transfer the money yo application account first?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Adaptive Payments API to handle the whole thing and the fee would get handled correctly so you don't get double dipped.  You'd have to rely on guest checkout for the credit card payments, though, which I know isn't ideal.

Another option would be to make a slight adjustment to what you're doing already.  The Pay API includes a parameter for the receivers called PAYMENTTYPE and this can be set to Personal.  This way, as long as the payment is made using PayPal or bank funds, there will no fee for the receiver.  In your case it sounds like that won't be an issue since you're paying with funds you just received so your PayPal balance should cover it just fine.

Comment: I tried it and it's working for the receivers, but I still have the problem that the fees is deducted once from the application account, I need to transfer the money to the receiver without the need of transfer the money to the application account first (if possible), also I don't mind that the fees is deducted from the receiver (the seller)

Comment: Ok, then just set the receiver to the person who you want to receive it instead of the application account.  Maybe I'm missing something..??

Comment: The problem is in the Adaptive SDK, I only found that I can make a transfer from one paypal account to one or more paypal accounts, I didn't find a way to send money directly from credit card to receivers, that's why I'm using paypal REST API, I wonder if there's a way to transfer the money from credit card to receivers directly

Comment: So the REST API is allowing you to split a credit card payment up into separate receivers?  I really haven't messed with REST much yet, but that would be interesting to see.  Are you sure it's letting you do that?

Comment: What you would probably need to do is use REST (or Payments Pro) to accept the credit card payment to your own account, but then within an IPN solution (or some other automated method) you could trigger a Pay request that sends the money from your account to the secondary receivers directly...just as a parallel payment, or even multiple single payments.

Comment: That's what I actually did, the problem is the paypal fees is deducted from the application account, both the buyer and the seller pay no fees, I want the fees to be deducted from the seller only, not the buyer or the application account

Comment: Hi sir, is Adaptive API still available or is it deprecated? I saw this on your website: "Adaptive Payments is not available for new integrations."

Comment: It is no longer available for new applications.  Instead, you should use the new PayPal Commerce Platform.